# Cannot query offerings of Glassfy in react native expo project

Tags: react-native, expo, in-app-purchase

So i want to add in-ap purchases in my app. I want to use Glassfy.

I have installed the package and installed expo-dev-client. This all works perfectly. I also imported the module and initialize it. This all works perfectly but then when i want to query the offerings its not working. What am i doing wrong?

```
import { Glassfy } from "react-native-glassfy-module";

return (
    try {
      await Glassfy.initialize('******************', false);
      console.log('succesfull')
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Glassify error')
    }
try {
      let offering = Glassfy.offerings.all.find((o) => o.offeringId === 'plus');
      offering?.skus.forEach((sku) => {
        console.log('sku')
        console.log(sku)
        // sku.extravars
        // sku.product.description;
        // sku.product.price
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Glassfy.offerings.all')
      console.log(Glassfy.offerings)
      console.log('error: ' + error);
    }
)
```

I already tried some things with the offering but this all is set up in glassfy. The console.log(Glassfy.offerings) gives me a function and not undefined so that is good i gues. I also have 2 offerings in glassfy but it would not work.

Does someone have a solution for me?